# How to handle Axe when he has Blink dagger / invis + blademail?

Tags: dota-2

Recently I played sniper, and since I was the only carry in team I went for a nearly glasscanon build. Mjol., Mask of Madness, Deadalus something like this.
I could snipe nearly all Enemy Heroes within 3-5 Hits but their axe could still blink to me and call me and activate his blademail. 
So what can I do to avoid this?

Either BKB and try to push it before the call comes?
Or Satanic and leech the hell out of him through blademail ?

These are the options I see, but there must be something better, or?

Comment: BKB won't help, Axe ignores it almost completely.

Comment: @Decency BKB ignore blademail damage at least

Comment: Can I activate BKB when I am already called?

Comment: @RayofCommand No

Comment: @WizLiz Yeah, but when Axe is under the effects of Call he has +40 armor and so he takes barely any damage anyway. Blademail is kind of a weak item on Axe for that reason.

Comment: @Decency it's not weak, it's simply not meant to be used during Call. But the problem is that the only time 1 or more heroes are forced to attack you is during Call. People mistake Axe for Clockwerk

Comment: @T_O Yeah, Axe is already a hero you don't want to be attacking even without Blademail. I could see it as a viable item for him against AoE magic damage, but that's about it.

Comment: as a sniper you have a nice attack speed. especially in the lategame and counter helix has 0.3 "cd" and hits you for 190. Let axe call a sniper for 3.2 seconds and spin 5 times. you are dead anyway. since he will use autoattacks in that time + battle hunger. and then dunk you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### When playing a glasscanon

First of all, when you are sniper you are **the** target. I can't think of any other hero in the game that people like to kill as much as sniper. The reason is easy, you are as tanky and as fast as a [guimauve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:White_Marshmallows.jpg).

So there are simple rules to follow (those apply to any glasscanon) :

- Never (ever) be in front when you push/def/gank etc. You stay in the back, and you watch where the enemy heroes are, then you position yourself accordingly.
- Having an escape mechanism is not necessary but strongly recommended. It can be a Shadowblade (classic) but you can also go with forcestaff or blink dagger. The latters allow you to reposition yourself through the teamfight and Sniper desperately need good positioning. The furthest the better. Plus it allows you to kite melee heroes really easily.
- If you're going glasscanon, always save a spot for BKB because the best item versus glasscanon heroes is a blade mail. Since blademail deals pure damage, you can have your BKB ready for when the blademail is activated so you no longer take reflected damage. I usually build BKB as a 3rd item (boot excluded). Something like Maelstorm > Cristalys > BKB then upgrade into Mjolnir and Daedalus. And if I feel like I need it I get my escape mechanism right after boots.
- Go for easy target. As you said you can 2/3 shots squishy heroes so when a fight start, activate your BKB to avoid normal disables (not Axe's Call) and magic/pure damage and snipe the support really fast, usually the fight is won at that point.

If you feel like you want to tank a little more, consider the following :

- As mentioned above : BKB versus magic burst, disables and blade mail
- Satanic is a viable choice. The active last 3.5 sec  while Axe Berserker's call last up to 3.2 sec so you can pretty much tank the whole thing with a satanic. Plus it give strength which upgrade the health of your illusion if you have a Manta Style
- Heart of Tarrasque is situational. Get it versus heroes that deal pure damage. Since pure damage ignores armor, having more raw HP helps a lot. Same as Satanic, your illusion benefit from the HP as well.

### When playing versus axe

Axe doesn't have a truly reliable disable so you can pretty much ignore him through the fight. He sole purpose in lategame is usually to get a good initation and finish off the low life targets. Being spread out, having good defensive/offensive wards, having a gem are the only things required to no be bothered anymore. If you can see where he is and if he fails his initation, he will pretty much die for nothing. Axe is what you can call a "one trick pony" hero, blink > call > culling blade. If he can no longer do that, he become pretty much useless. Also Axe relies on snowballing to get more items. Afk farming the jungle is not efficient enough for him to stay there for 20 min so avoid dying in early game (I repeat myself but wards are the key here) and he won't be an issue later at all.

Comment: For clarity - Axe's call increases his armour by 40, so if Axe blink -> calls -> blademail against sniper, does the damage that blademail returns take account of sniper's armour, or axe's? i.e. is sniper's right-click damage during the call reduced by axe's armour before it is returned by blademail?

Comment: @Cheeseburger If Axe calls and Blademails, Sniper will deal low damage and take low damage in return. Blademail is not very strong during Call

Comment: @Cheeseburger What T_O said, blademail is actually more usefull versus magic burst. Or glasscanon that forget to build a bkb because they cant attack you or they'll die

Comment: @WizLiz Satanic is a viable option against blademail I think. Blink is also a great way to kite Axe but you addressed that in your post

Comment: Thanks WizLiz, yep I tried to stand behind and it was working out well most of the time. but we needed more wards. I play as well for a lot of fun and I love to rambo that'S why I don't buy shadow blade lol. maybe i should get one escape item in the next game. Thanks

Comment: I cannot agree with your second part of your answer. Axe's Call is a strong disable. Not only does it make the enemy unable to use spells or items, it also goes through bkb(!) and can be used to make enemies move to your team. If a farmed sniper is on the field every axe should try to go for him first because without sniper most teams will lose the rest of the fight.

Comment: Furthermore because he is such a good initiator and disabler he should focus on the main carry if possible to give his team 3 seconds to kill that carry of or to force the enemy supports to collapse on him -> resulting in your team bashing the clumped enemy team with aoe.

Comment: @Wandang that's why I said "strong", but reliable is a more appropriate term. Plus you must be in close range to use it and you can get kited/baited (if enemy has good vision) really easily so I would not call berserk call a strong disable. Its purely situational, generally it follows a blink from Axe and pub gamle lacking coordination, you more than often lose a huge amount of the berserks call time trying to position and catch up with the teamfight